# why element in html like (drop down, button, textbox) do not reachabel with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to change or at least make any small effect in the korean custom website but it seems they are not accessible by my code! Maybe they are in the internal iframe or not, I don't know. I want to ****change dropdown**, **write** something in **textbox** and click **search button****, but I *cannot*.

May anyone help me?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
webdriver_service = Service('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url = 'http://www.kita.org/kStat/byCom_AllCount.do'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

select = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select')))) # select dropdown
select.select_by_index(1)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/img').click()  #click seach Button
time.sleep(5)
```

[image]

Comment: Which dropdown are you trying to click, and what option are you trying to select?

Comment: @ Barry the Platipus . you always save my work.

Comment: @ Barry the Platipus. imp/Exp dropdown "import" and "search" button

Comment: The `xpath` for import dropdown is incorrect. Use this `//select[@name="cond_ie_gb"]`

Comment: @Akzy no it doesn't work with your xpath. however thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an iframe there.
You need to switch to it first in order to access elements in it.
Also, you should improve your locators.
And insert some text into the item input.
The following code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "http://www.kita.org/kStat/byCom_AllCount.do"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe_stat")))

select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='cond_choosefield']"))))
select.select_by_index(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='cond_prdt_cd']"))).send_keys("kuku")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='searchForm']"))).click()
```

Comment: I know :) You are welcome!